# Mask a url to use a subdomain url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdomain, multisite

On a WordPress multisite, I need an HTML file to be shown as if it is in a subdomain that doesn't exist in reality but does on the multisite. I've tried quite a few `htaccess` variations to no avail.

```
mydomain.example/myfile.html
```

should be shown with a url of

```
mysub.mydomain.example/myfile.html
```

Since I can not have the file in a place that does not exist I just want the URL masked as being in the subdomain while the file is in its same location.

Any advice or solutions while I continue my research would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue here? If your http server responds to that subdomain, then you can rewrite an incoming request to whatever you want. And you can externally redirect requests to that subdomain too, if required. Take a look at apache's proxy module which can be integrated into the rewriting module. As always, the documentation is your friend, it offers very good examples.

Comment: You are right, this was user error on my part of course. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the file there, and reference it with whatever subdomain you want. If you have wildcard DNS setup properly, which you should if you have a Subdomain Multisite set up, it will work just fine.

You can see it working here:

http://doesntexist.thirdriverlocalsearch.com/1000x160.png

http://fakeurl.thirdriverlocalsearch.com/1000x160.png

http://thirdriverlocalsearch.com/1000x160.png

That image just exists in the `/public_html/` directory, and those subdomains (of course) are fake and haven't actually been set up.

Comment: WOW you are right, when I tried that yesterday I had an SSL error in the browser and wouldn't load and I wrote it off. BUT it was a network issue that they fixed last night and you are completely right.

Comment: Yea the SSL error would have been irrelevant to this issue, and clicking the "proceed even though it's dangerous" would have let you view the file. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: That isn't an option on our iron clad network here, we ONLY get: Can’t connect securely to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner."